# Cannot import shared object file which is in the same directory

Tags: python

I have the following file structure inside (so_output):

```
CVAPIV01_DESFire (C/C++ Header)
libCVAPIV01_DESFire (Python File)
libCVAPIV01_DESFire (SO File)
test (Python file)
```

And my `test.py` code is the following:

```
import libCVAPIV01_DESFire
CV_SetCommunicationType(1)
ActiveBuzzer(0,1,[])
```

My `libCVAPIV01_DESFire.py` code is the following:

```
def __bootstrap__():
   global __bootstrap__, __loader__, __file__
   import sys, pkg_resources, imp
   __file__ = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__,'libCVAPIV01_DESFire.so')
   __loader__ = None; del __bootstrap__, __loader__
   imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)
__bootstrap__()
```

Upon running test.py trying to import I get an import error on a Raspberry Pi, the shared object file is ARM based which matches the Raspberry Pi.

This is a fresh Pi installation running libusb and PyUSB.

The error is:[image]

Any ideas? I'm very new to Python and I'm thinking this is just a case of setting the right path or putting the shared object file somewhere appropriate.

Text based output error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
      import libCVAPIV01_DESFire
ImportError: /home/pi/Desktop/so_output/libCVAPIV01_DESFire.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**Edit:** Still trying to figure this out hours on... I've gone down to:

```
import ctypes
testlib = ctypes.CDLL('/home/pi/Desktop/so_output/libCVAPIV01_DESFire.so')
```

in `test.py`, and yet here's the same error...

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/so_output $ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    testlib = ctypes.CDLL('/home/pi/Desktop/so_output/libCVAPIV01_DESFire.so')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /home/pi/Desktop/so_output/libCVAPIV01_DESFire.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: weird indeed. Can you post the copy of your console _as text_ and not as an image. If there's a subtlety, it will be better with some text.

Comment: it is indeed. I'm starting to think it's because I haven't set the environment, e.g. not having a folder for my libs where I store things like a shared object that Python can index and find.

Comment: I would check if file exists before `imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)`: `if not os.path.isfile(__file__): raise Exception(__file__)`

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't it be a case of linking up my shared object though, I feel like Python can't find it. Maybe a case of editing my bash file and pointing it to the directory of where my SO is?

Comment: Could it be a problem with Python not being able to read the .SO file? @Jean-FrançoisFabre. I've edited the code to a simple format to use this:

`import ctypes
import os

testlib = ctypes.CDLL('/home/pi/Desktop/so_output/libCVAPIV01_DESFire.so')`

which should run...but again, the same error.